# QGIS color polygon according to points

Tags: qgis, topography

I have two layers. Layer 1 contains points (x,y) and layer 2 contains one polygon. All points in layer 1 are positioned within the polygon of layer 2. The points in layer 1 contain an attribute with information on the topography/elevation at the specific point. Can I color the polygon in layer 2 based on attributes from the points in layer 1 in order to create an elevation map?

Comment: is it an option to join the 2 layers so you would have the elevation in the polygon layer?

Answer (score 1):

If joining the layers is an option I suggest to go  the processing toolbar and there under QGIS geoalgorithms -> Vector general tools and there use the tool "Join attributes by location"

[image]
As you can see in the Screenshot it takes several inputs so if every Polygone just contains one point you could stick with the option "Take the attributes of first ... " if not you could use the statistics. The tool will create a new layer, however. The Target layer would be your polygon layer while the points layer would be the joining layer.

Afterward just style the newly created layer with the elevation as classification value

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I tried using the "join attributes by location function". However, the resulting layer only contains one row of attributes. Layer 1 however, contains approximately 900,000 points which I would like to see conserved in layer 2. After all, I want to colorize layer 2 according to the information in the individual points.

Comment: @Jonas  How many polygons does your layer 2 have? because It wont add any new polygons.

Comment: Just one polygon

Comment: @Jonas you could rasterize your points with qgis. This seems to be the only option in that case. Besides whats your aim?

Comment: I want to create a polygon which is colored according to the elevation data provided by the points which I have.

Comment: The short answer to your question is "No." Polygons just aren't designed to do that. What you're describing is basically a raster.

Answer (score 1):

The only option I can think of is to generate a raster elevation model from the point layer, then clip that resulting raster with the polygon layer so that any cell outside of the polygon boundary are NODATA. Then you can display the raster with the polygon outline above it.

relevant tools:

- [Rasterize](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdalogr/gdal_conversion/rasterize.html)
- [Clipper](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/fr/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_gdaltools.html#extraction)